Why does subgroup definition imply closure of binary operation?
I'm reading Basic Abstract Algebra (2nd edition) by
P. B. Bhattacharya, S. K. Jain, and S. R. Nagpaul, and struggling with their very basic definition of a subgroup, and why it implies that it must be closed under the binary operation.
I'm reproducing the relevant definitions from their book below.

A binary operation $*$ is a function $* : G \times G \to G$, where $G$ is a set. A group is a tuple $(G,*)$, such that

$a*(b * c) = (a * b) * c$ for all $a,b,c \in G$.
There exists $e \in G$ such that $a * e = e * a = a$ for all $a \in G$.
For every $a \in G$ there exists $a' \in G$ such that $a * a' = a' * a = e$.

A subset $H$ of $G$ is subgroup if $H$ is a group relative to the binary operation in $G$.

Many definitions of a group also include a closure requirement (e.g. here), namely that $a * b \in G$ for all $a,b \in G$. This is not required in the definition above, since the closure property is already "baked into" the definition of the binary operator $*$. However, it's not obvious to me why this closure property must be inherited by the subset $H$. Indeed, Bhattacharya et al. states this as a theorem.

3.2 Theorem. Let $(G,*)$ be a group. A nonempty finite subset $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup if and only if $a*b \in H$ for all $a,b \in H$.

But they simply dismiss this as trivial!

Proof. ... The converse [i.e. $a * b \in H \implies H$ is a subgroup] is obvious. $\square$

However, I'm not convinced. Here's my objection. We're given $* : G \times G \to G$, and we assume that $H$ is a subgroup, thus the three axioms above are satisfied for all $a,b \in H$. But $*$ is only guaranteed to be a function from $G \times G$ to $G$, not from $H \times H$ to $H$. That is, since $H \subset G$, the product $a * b$ is of course well-defined as an element in $G$, but how can we be certain that $a * b \in H$ from axioms (1), (2) and (3) above?
Stated differently, we can of course consider the restriction $*|_H : H \times H \to G$, but why is it guaranteed that $*|_H : H \times H \to H$ just from (1), (2) and (3)?

Because the definition of group requires that the function be an operation. By definition, a binary operation on a set $S$ is a function $S\times S\to S$. Saying that $H$ is "a group under the binary operation in $G$" means that the restriction of $*$ to $H\times H$ is an operation on $H$... hence that the product of elements of $H$ lies in $H$.

The author says $H$ is a subgroup if it is a group with respect to the operation $*$. So in particular he assumes that this is a binary operation on $H$, i.e the product of two elements of $H$ is an element of $H$. I fully understand why it looks confusing though.

@Mark Thanks, I've also assumed that's what's going on. I'm not satisfied with that for two reasons. (1) When defining $H$ as a subgroup, it is not with a new operation, but rather the same $$ that was defined for $G$, now simply restricted to a subset of the elements in $G$. It is not defined as "$$ but restricted only to those $a,b,\in H$ for which $a * b \in H$". They're talking about an arbitrary subset. A priori it's conceivable that one could define an $$ on $G$ such that $ab$ would "land outside" $H$. (2) If the definition is restricted in this way, then shouldn't that

...be reflected in the definition of $H$?

Should stress:  The Theorem you cite is more about finiteness than it is about closure.  The claim would be false if you dropped finiteness...For example, the natural numbers are closed under addition but they aren't a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$.

@lulu I only used the finite version (Theorem 3.2) since it was cleaner to state. But they also have an infinite version: "3.1 Theorem. [...] $H$ is a subgroup iff either of the following holds: (i) for all $a,b\in H$, $a*b \in H$ and $a^{-1} \in H$. (ii) For all $a,b \in H$, $ab^{-1} \in H$."

Not at all.  Inverses do not exist in the natural numbers so the first test fails, and if $a=1, b=10$,  $a+ (-b)\not \in \mathbb N$ so the second test fails as well.

@lulu, yeah, sorry, I mixed things up regarding the naturals vs. integers. Removed that. But my point/question still stands: even without the finiteness requirement, there doesn't seem to be anything in their definition that guarantees that subgroup implies closure (like Arturo and Mark above, you seem to presuppose that closure is part of the subgroup definition, but that's exactly the issue I have: their definition doesn't seem to require that, but they claim that it follows as a theorem [if closure is part of the definition, then why include the theorem?])

The definition requires $*$ to be an operation on $H$, which in turn requires closure.  The given  Theorem ($3.2$) holds that for finite subsets of a group, closure is enough to imply that the subset is a subgroup.  That's not at all obvious, though it is easy enough to prove.  Again, for infinite subsets the theorem is not true, but for finite subsets that's all you need.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

When you say "in particular ... assumes that this is a binary operation on $H$ , i.e the product of two elements of $H$ is an element of $H$" , then the theorem 3.2 is simply restating that assumption , @Mark , which is redundant. Actually the Authors are not assuming that : The Authors wrongly claim to Derive that , yet it is faulty here !

Prem: there is nothing "alternate" about the definition here. Don't project your lack of familiarity with how group is defined here onto the question. I've rolled back your tendentious edit of the title line.

Whether my edits are rolled back or not , that is what OP is claiming with "many Definitions of a group ... closure requirement" & "This is not required in the definition above" , I merely highlighted that Contrast in the title. The Crux of the question , @ArturoMagidin , is over the 2 Definitions , one normal & one alternate , or Def1 & Def2. If you claim that those 2 are Same , then that is the Answer to the Question , though the Question will remain about 2 Definitions.

You keep using tendentious wording. Again: "normal" and "alternate" are not objective terms. You are literally claiming that what you are used to is "normal" and what you are not used to is "alternate". That is not the case. That is just a reflection of your lack of knowledge and familiarity. So stop projecting your inadequacies onto others. It's not an "alternate" definition, it's a different one. The one you are familiar to is not "normal", it's just "the one you are familiar with". It's not "new way", it's "a way you have not seen before."

The wording of the authors is perhaps less than crystal, so that someone who is less used to the notion of a "binary operation" might get the wrong impression. But the definition is not an uncommon way of defining "substructure" in the context of, say, universal algebra.
It would have been better if the authors had stuck to their notation. Namely, they are defining a group to be an ordered pair $(G,*)$, where $G$ is a set, and $*$ is a binary operation on $G$ (so a function $*\colon G\times G\to G$) that satisfies properties 1, 2, and 3.
When they say that a subset $H$ "is a subgroup" if it "is a group relative ot the binary operation on $G$", what they mean is that the ordered pair $(H,*|_{H\times H})$ is a group. Because in order to be a group, the second component of the ordered pair must be a binary operation on the first component (which must be a set), this means that the restriction of $*$ to $H\times H$ is an operation on $H$... and therefore that it takes inputs in $H\times H$ and has outputs in $H$. So the "closure" of $H$ is implicit in saying that $*|_{H\times H}$ is an operation.
This is less than clear, among other reasons because it is not $H$ that is a "group" (they have defined groups to be ordered pairs). They have not told us yet that they will often refer to a group by the name of its underlying set and leave the operation to be understood from context. To be fair to the authors, very few authors bother to make the distinction, and even fewer remember to warn the reader that they will do that elision. (One of the few who is consistently careful about this and yet manages to not obscure his points with the additional notation is George Bergman in his Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions).
It would be more correct to say that a subset $H$ determines (rather than "is") a subgroup, since bare sets are not groups. Something like:

A subset $H$ of $G$ determines a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $(H,*|_{H\times H})$ is a group.

So, under the definition, if $H$ is a subset of $G$, with $(G,*)$ a group, in order to verify that $H$ determines a subgroup of $G$ you would need, in principle, to check two things, though one of them is really three things:

That the restriction of $*$ to $H\times H$ is an operation on $H$.
That the resulting pair $(H,*|_{H\times H})$ is a group.

Using $\star$ to denote $*|_{H\times H}$ in order to de-clutter, establishing point 2 would mean verifying that (i) $a\star(b\star c) = (a\star b)\star c$ for all $a,b,c\in H$; (ii) there exists $E\in H$ such that $E\star a = a\star E = a$ for all $a\in H$; and (iii) for all $a\in H$ there exists $\overline{a}\in H$ such that $a\star \overline{a} = \overline{a}\star a = E$.
Now, as it turns out (i) is automatically satisfies by $\star$ in $H$ because it is satisfies by $*$ in $G$. So verifying that $H$ determines a subgroup usually devolves into verifying three things: that $\star$ is an operation, which requires verifying that if $a,b\in H$ then $a\star b\in H$; that is, the "closure" that you are concerned with; that the element $e$ of $G$ lies in $H$, as that is the only element that may satisfy (ii) relative to $\star$; and that if $a\in H$ then $a'\in H$, because the $a'$ from $G$ is the only one that can play the role of $\overline{a}$.
Now, the Theorem is saying something different. What the Theorem is saying is that when the subset $H$ is finite, then you really only  need to verify the first of the two (secretly four) properties listed, that is,

If $(G,*)$ is a group, and $H$ is a nonempty finite subset of $G$, then $H$ determines a subgroup if and only if the restriction $*|_{H\times H}$ is an operation on $H$.

Whereas the definition of subgroup requires that the restriction be an operation and that the identity element of $*$ be in $H$, and that the inverse of any element of $H$ also be in $H$; the theorem says that for finite subsets, it is enough to verify that the restriction is an operation, and the additional three (really only two that matter, as associativity is "free") requirements will be met.
You can stop here. What's under the horizontal line is some stuff related to a more general vista.

From the point of view of universal algebra, a group really has three (not one) operations: a binary operation $*$, a unary operation ${}^{-1}$, and a nullary operation $e$ satisfying the following identities:

$a*(b*c) = (a*b)*c$;
$e*a = a*e = a$;
$a*{}^{-1}(a) = {}^{-1}(a)*a = e$.

Then we would say that a subset $H$ of $G$ determines a subgroup if and only if the restrictions of these operations are operations on $H$. This would be what is often called (i) "$H$ is closed under products"; (ii) "$H$ contains the identity"; and (iii) "$H$ is closed under inverses".
A semigroup would then just be a pair $(S,*)$; and the theorem says that a nonempty finite subset of a group is a subgroup if and only if it is a subsemigroup. This is in keeping with, for instance, the fact that we should "really" require that group homomorphisms be functions $f\colon G_1\to G_2$ with $(G_1,(*,{}^{-1},e))$ and $(G_2,(\cdot,\overline{\ },E))$ group, such that (i) $f(a*b)= f(a)\cdot f(b)$; (ii) $f(e)=E$; and (iii) $f(a^{-1}) = \overline{f(a)}$. And then one prove that $f\colon G_1\to G_2$ is a group homomorphism if and only if it is a semigroup homomorphism from $(G_1,*)$ to $(G_2,\star)$. This explains, for instance, why when you are working with rings with unity you should always require morphisms to be unital (send the unity to the unity). We acquire a lot of bad habits from the fact that groups are pretty nice relative to these properties...
